# Fastest way to register namespaces programatically

Tags: r, namespaces

I'm building a function that uses `getAnywhere()` to retrieve the different packages from which a given function can be exported.

Unfortunately, `getAnywhere()` is limited to functions that exist in a loaded namespace, so I need to register the one I use.

Time is a constraint here, as loading a lot of namespaces can be a bit long (>10s), so using `library()` or `require()` is not realistic.

In RStudio, simply printing a prefixed function is enough to register the whole namespace without loading the library:

```r
getAnywhere("align")$where
#> character(0)

flextable::as_flextable
#> function (x, ...) 
#> {
#>     UseMethod("as_flextable")
#> }
#> <bytecode: 0x000000002158e7f0>
#> <environment: namespace:flextable>

getAnywhere("align")$where
#> [1] "namespace:xtable"    "namespace:flextable"

pkgload::unload("flextable")
getAnywhere("align")$where
#> [1] "namespace:xtable"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-06-29 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

As you can see:

- at first, no loaded namespace contain a function named "align"
- after printing any function from `flextable`, `xtable` and `flextable` are stated (`xtable` is a dependency of `flextable`)
- for the example, after unloading `flextable`, only `xtable` remains

This seems fast enough, but it is hard-coded.

How could I register the `flextable` namespace programmatically (along with others)?
Is there an even faster way to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, there is a fast little function obviously named `base::loadNamespace()`. Don't know how I missed it...

```r
getAnywhere("align")$where
#> character(0)
loadNamespace("flextable")
#> <environment: namespace:flextable>
getAnywhere("align")$where
#> [1] "namespace:xtable"    "namespace:flextable"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-06-30 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to use functions from existing packages, you can use use `attach()/detach()` to quickly put things on and off the search path

```
getAnywhere("align")$where
# character(0)
x <- list(align=function() 1)
attach(x)
getAnywhere("align")$where
# [1] "x"
detach(x)
getAnywhere("align")$where
# character(0)
```

Comment: I don't need to use the function, but the point was actually to have the namespace available so `getAnywhere()` doesn't miss a possible source. In your example, flextable is not showing up.

Comment: That's because I never loaded it in this example. `getAnywhere` will only search in loaded packages. So is this question specifically about `flextable`? Or are you asking about unloading all of a package dependencies after you load it? R wasn't really designed with the idea that you would be unloading things. It gets messy when multiple packages share common dependencies.

Comment: My question was about how to load a namespace, not how to unload (as I gave an example of `pkgload::unload()`). I've rewrote my question, I hope it is clearer now.